# FTP upload with alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, ftp, alamofire, xcode8

I dont know what am i doing wrong? can anybody help

```
   let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 30)!

        Alamofire.upload(imageData, to: "ftp://username:password@ip:21/")
            .uploadProgress{ Progress in print("Upload Progress : \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")}
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            })
```

Error:

```
responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Number with minus sign but no digits around character 1." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Number with minus sign but no digits around character 1.}))
```

Using xcode8 and swift.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different library. Alamofire supports only the http/https protocols.

Comment: Do you have any idea about another library?